# What happened to the CodeFirst bits in the latest EntityFramework version available at Nuget?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

Frustrated: Ran an update on my packages, which included EFCodeFirst. Was told that package is now obsolete by the package manager, and it installed the latest version of EntityFramework (4.1.10311.0). Now I can't find references for my contexts (DbContext, DbSet are both broken). Where the heck did those go? Did they get renamed? What happened to the CodeFirst stuff?

Comment: I'd down vote my own question if I could...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the code first bits are in EF 4.1

```
System.Data.Entity.DbContext
```

Make sure you have added a reference to the new EntityFramework.dll in any project using EF code first. There are some changes in EF 4.1 and CPT5 that you can read about here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx

Here is a walk through of upgrading an existing app using CPT5: http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/upgrading-to-entity-framework-4-1-rc/

Comment: Turns out I had some remnant references causing me trouble. Frustratio leads to stupid questions sometimes... Thanks!